# Change the url associated with cancel button

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to change the URL of cancel button presently on canceling the page it is showing me the list but I want to redirect the user on the cancel button.

[image: For Genrated by using renderform()]

```
public function renderForm() {
        $this->fields_form = array(
            'legend' => array('title' => $this->l('Additional Service'), 'icon' => 'icon-cogs'),
            'input' => array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->l('id_citydelivery'),
                    'name' => 'id_citydelivery',
                    'size' => 255),
                array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->l('Service_name'),
                    'name' => 'service_name',
                    'size' => 255,
                    'required' => true,
                    'desc' => $this->l('Enter name of Arrival port')
                ),
                array(
                    'type' => 'switch',
                    'label' => $this->l('Active'),
                    'name' => 'active',
                    'required' => false,
                    'is_bool' => true,
                    'values' => array(array(
                            'id' => 'active_on',
                            'value' => 1,
                            'label' => $this->l('Active')), array(
                            'id' => 'active_off',
                            'value' => 0,
                            'label' => $this->l('Inactive')))),
            ),
            'submit' => array('title' => $this->l('Save')),
        );
        return parent::renderForm();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

After Diving into the code I came to know back button URL is set it by $_post['Back']
So I have overridden it; you have to change # with your URL

```
public function postProcess() {
    if (Tools::getIsset('submitAddadditional_service')) {
        $this->redirect_after = Context::getContext()->link->getAdminLink('AdminGCardeliverycity', true) . '&updatecitydelivery&id_citydelivery=' . Tools::getValue('id_citydelivery');
    } else {
        $_POST['back'] = '#'; //For Cancel button url on form which is genrated by renderform()   
    }
    parent::postProcess();
}
```